# Find all files, and copy them to a folder (Flatten recursively)

Tags: bash, macos, find

Basically, I have a very large filesystem that contains media. It has a ton of silly subfolders. I'd like to find all the *files* (any file) and copy them flatly into a directory. What's the best/easiest way to do this?

Assume that the directory of media is located at `/home/user/media`  and the location of the destination directory is `/home/user/flatmedia`

I'd like to do this using standard mac tools.

Comment: What do you want to happen to files with the same name?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52366028/967621

Comment: To use a single command, you can create an alias, as shown here: [Command-line tool for flattening directories - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/88525/command-line-tool-for-flattening-directories/88528#88528)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`find /home/user/media  -type f -exec cp {} /home/user/flatmedia \;`

Note - if there are any duplicates there's no particular guarantee about which one you'll get.

Comment: The `-type f` means "flatten" ;)

Comment: [Just in case anyone is confused by the joke, it actually means "restrict the find to files, as opposed to directories etc" :-)]

Comment: This is great! Can you explain what the curly brackets do?

Comment: They get substituted for each thing that `find` finds.