# Auto overwrite when flattening file structure in OSX

Tags: bash, macos, find, mv

I'm trying to flatten a directory in OS X which contains many duplicate files.

So far i have....

```
find /directory -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -i '{}' /directory ';'
```

But this responds asking me many times:

```
overwrite /directory/file.xml? (y/n [n]) 
not overwritten
```

Please can someone help me with the flag to auto accept yes/no to this and where it should be included in the above command?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20211911/967621

Comment: To use a single command, you can create an alias, as shown here: [Command-line tool for flattening directories - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/88525/command-line-tool-for-flattening-directories/88528#88528)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the option `-f` instead of `-i` for `mv` command

```
find /directory -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -f '{}' /directory ';'
```

In the manual of `mv`:

```
 -f      Do not prompt for confirmation before overwriting the destination path.  (The -f option overrides any
         previous -i or -n options.)

 -i      Cause mv to write a prompt to standard error before moving a file that would overwrite an existing file.
         If the response from the standard input begins with the character `y' or `Y', the move is attempted.
         (The -i option overrides any previous -f or -n options.)
```